# New coder trying to do a Newton-Rhapson method code

Tags: c++

So I have been learning how to code in c++, but out of nowhere my teacher gave us an assigment of doing a Newton-Rhapson method with a equation given by him, I have been trying for a week now and searchin on different pages, but i am stuck in a error that says:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: main.cpp:42:105: error: expected primary-expression before ‘<<’ token 42 | cout<<"iteracion-"<< step<<":\t x = "<< setw(10)<< x1<<" y f(x) = "<< setw(10)<< f(x1)<< endl; |

^~
```

My code is:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define f(x) (0.95 * pow(x, 3.0) - 5.9 * pow(x, 2.0) + 10.9 * x - 6.0);

#define g(x) (2.85 * pow(x, 2.0) - 11.8 * x -+ 10.9);

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  float x0, x1, f0, f1, g0, e;
  int step = 1, N;
  
  cout << setprecision (6) << fixed;

  cout << "Agregar estimación inicial: ";
  cin >> x0;
  cout << "Agergar error tolerable: ";
  cin >> e;
  cout << "Agragar iteracion maxima: ";
  cin >> N;
  cout << endl << "*******" << endl;
  cout << "Metodo Newton Raphson " << endl;
  cout << "*******" << endl;
  
  do {
    g0 = g (x0);
    f0 = f (x0);
    
    if (g0 == 0.0)
    {
      cout << "Error matematico.";
      exit (0);
    }

    x1 = x0 - f0 / g0;

    cout << "iteracion-" << step << ":\t x = " << setw (10) << x1 <<
            " y f(x) = " << setw (10) << f (x1) << endl;

    x0 = x1;
    /* (this is where the error comes from) */
    step = step + 1;

    if (step > N)
    {
      cout << "No Convergente.";
      exit (0);
    }

    f1 = f (x1);


  } while (fabs (f1) > e);
  
  cout << endl << "Raiz: " << x1;
  return 0;
}
```

I have been searching everywhere, from videos to pages with similar codes, but i still don't understand what to do in order to solve the problem.

Comment: The answer to your specific question is given well by others. But your problem largely arose because of the use of macros (#define ) in the first place. Your teacher may well have said “define a function that…”, but that doesn’t mean using #define. Create separate functions f() and g(). Also, with a numerical method requiring tight precision to judge convergence, use double rather than float. Finally, -+ should be just + in the derivative function g()

Comment: Your calculus is wrong. The derivative of `0.95x^3 - 5.9x^2 + 10.9x - 6` is `2.85x^2 - 11.8x + 10.9` -- the `-` sign at the end of `g(x)` is wrong, remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `define`s have a semicolon:

```cpp
#define f(x) (0.95 * pow(x, 3.0) - 5.9 * pow(x, 2.0) + 10.9 * x - 6.0);
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
#define g(x) (2.85 * pow(x, 2.0) - 11.8 * x -+ 10.9);
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

So when you use them with `cout`, you're ending the expression sooner than you'd expect. Remove the semicolon from the `define`s.

Comment: The `x -+ 10.9` is worth a comment as well -- pick one or make it `- +10.9` so it is clear.

Comment: Note: you need to remove the `-` sign completely in `x -+ 10.9` for `g(x)` to be the proper derivative of `f(x)` -- what Newton-Rhapson requires.